# I used str_replace to get values to database without comma separator and decimal point. Now, how to return from database in old format?

Tags: php, mysql, database

My form has a comma separator and decimal point. I used str_replace to get values to the database without comma separator and decimal point. Now, I want to return from the database to view with comma separator and decimal point. Plz, help!
My code in (Codeigniter) model is

```
function saveOpeningTrialBalance_m(){
    $data=array(
        $len=>$this->input->post('len');
        $code=>$this->input->post('code');
        $date=>$this->input->post('date');
        $debit=>str_replace(',','',($this->input->post('debit')));
        $credit=>str_replace(',','',($this->input->post('credit')));
        $status=>$this->input->post('status');
        );
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
        if($status[$i]=='i'){
            $data=array(
                'ACCTCODE'=>$code[$i],
                'CREATED_DATE'=>$date[$i],
                'DEBIT'=>$debit[$i],                      
                'CREDIT'=>$credit[$i]
                ); 
            $insert=$this->db->insert('gl_opening_balance',$data);
            // return $insert; 
        }
        else if ($status[$i]=='m') {
            $dataUpdate=array(
                'ACCTCODE'=>$code[$i],
                'CREATED_DATE'=>$date[$i],
                'DEBIT'=>$debit[$i],                      
                'CREDIT'=>$credit[$i]
                );
            $this->db->where('ACCTCODE',$code[$i]);
            $update=$this->db->update('gl_opening_balance',$dataUpdate);
            return $update;   
        }
        else if($status[$i]=='d'){
            $where=array('ACCTCODE'=>$code[$i]
                );
            //$data=array("DEL"=>1);
            $this->db->where($where);
            $update=$this->db->delete('gl_opening_balance',$where);

        }

    }
    return $insert;

}
```

Comment: Use `number_format()`?

Comment: how is `javascript` at all relevant to this question?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, where we call back, use:- number_format($row[''], 2, '.', ',')

`$data[]=array($row['ACCTCODE'],$row['ACCTNAME'],$row['PARENT'],$row['DOC_DATE'],number_format($row['DEBIT'], 2, '.', ','),number_format($row['credit'], 2, '.', ','),'e', "id='".$row['ACCTCODE']."'");`